# Help with parsing lines of a file and replacing a substring

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, file, parsing

I need to replace certain characters in each line of a file.  The file is not delimited, but each line has a fixed format.  For example, I need to replace 5 questionmarks into 'x's.  The 5 questionmarks that need to be replaced in each line are found in position 10.  So for example:

Input file:

```
abdfg trr?????456
g?????dhs?????diu
eerrttyycdhjjhddd
```

The output file should be:

```
abdfg trrxxxxx456
g?????dhsxxxxxdiu
eerrttyycdhjjhddd
```

The output file will be saved as a different file to a specific location

What's the best way to do this in VB.NET (I'm a little new to VB, so any code sample would help)?

Comment: Is it always the same for every file, or does it vary between files? Also, is it always the same number of question marks?

Comment: Yes it's always the same number of questions marks, and always appears on the same index (same for each line).  Every file is different, but the format is the same...replace 5 questionmarks in position 10 of each line to xxxxx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible solution is to parse each line in the file using a [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) (via the [ReadLine()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx) method). As you read in each line, you can use a [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx) to write the original line out (via the [WriteLine(String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ack4zyt.aspx) method), with one adjustment. If the line meets your replacement requirements, you will use the [String.Replace(String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) method to swap out the old string for the replacement string.

Here is a solution (compiled and tested with your sample data above). You would still want to add some exception handling (at the very least, ensure the file exists first):

```
Public Shared Sub ReplacementExample(string originalFile, string newFile)

    ' Read contents of "oringalFile"
    ' Replace 5 ? characters with 5 x characters.
    ' Write output to the "newFile"
    ' Note: Only do so if the ? characters begin at position 10


    Const replaceMe As String = "?????"
    Const replacement As String = "xxxxx"

    Dim line As String = Nothing

    Using r As New StreamReader(originalFile)
        Using w As New StreamWriter(newFile)

            line = r.ReadLine()

            While Not line Is Nothing
                w.WriteLine(line.Substring(0, 9) + _
                            line.Substring(9).Replace(replaceMe, replacement))

                line = r.ReadLine()
            End While

        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: You may have to play around with the exception handling a bit. This will probably fail if the file is missing since the streams are being defined outside of a try/catch block. You get the point though.

Comment: @Probhu: No problem. I updated with a better example... didn't realize there were using blocks in VB.NET now.

Comment: Cleaned up the answer a little bit more. Might as well make it useful for other people that may read this later.

Answer (score 2):

Judging by provided source code position is `9`.

C# code:

```
var res = s.Substring(0, 9) + s.Substring(9).Replace("?????", "xxxxx");
```

VB.NET:

```
Dim res As String = (s.Substring(0, 9) & s.Substring(9).Replace("?????", "xxxxx"))
```

Example VB.NET:

```
Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader("a.txt")
        Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter("b.txt")
            Dim line As String = Nothing
            Do While (Not line = sr.ReadLine Is Nothing)
                Dim res As String = (line.Substring(0, 9) & line.Substring(9).Replace("?????", "xxxxx"))
                sw.WriteLine(res)
            Loop
        End Using
    End Using
```

Example C#:

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader("a.txt"))
{
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter("b.txt"))
    {
        string line = null;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            var res = line.Substring(0, 9) + line.Substring(9).Replace("?????", "xxxxx");
            sw.WriteLine(res);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So just read each line and do a string.replace for those indices?  There's no need to convert to an array or anything right?

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear, but I don't want to replace all occurrences of ????? on the line (there may be multiple ones).  I just want to replace the ones occurring in position/index 10.

Comment: It depends on file size. If it small, for example, `File.ReadAllText`, replace strings, write to output. If file is large, reading/replacing/writing by row is more appropriate.

Comment: @Prabhu, Updated answer again.